# Как убрать обертку list-view data-key yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как убрать обертку list-view data-key yii2(оборачивает каждую итерацию) `div data-key="id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо в параметрах itemOptions для ListView указать отказ от тега, например:

```
ListView::widget([
    'itemOptions' => [
        'tag' => false,
    ],
])
```

Здесь более подробно описано http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemOptions-detail.

> The "tag" element specifies the tag name of the container element and
>   defaults to "div". If "tag" is false, it means no container element
>   will be rendered.